# Unable to create converter for class

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, fragment, retrofit

I am using retrofit in my app and Gson convertor for JSON. I would like to use database when there is not internet connection. I decided to use Sugar ORM. 
but I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class

here is my object

```
public class User extends SugarRecord implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    @Expose
    private String lastname;
    @SerializedName("properties")
    @Expose @Ignore
    private List<Object> properties = new ArrayList<>();
    @SerializedName("rights")
    @Expose @Ignore
    private String rights;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    @Expose
    private String photo;
    @SerializedName("favorites")
    @Expose @Ignore
    private List<PointsOnMap> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String lastname, String email, String photo, String token) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.token = token;
    }
    //getters and setters
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: look the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42517143/703225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you can't have a variable named `id` in your class when using Sugar since by default it uses its own internal ids. Try renaming to `userId` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **transient** statement before **Integer** type.

```
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private transient Integer id;
```

Then, if you have **getId** and **setId** methods, should delete them.

And have fun!